# App doesen't execute on emulator

Tags: android-emulator

hello i have problem with emulator in my computer. emulator starts but don't show hello world app in emulator and don't show android desktop and show black screen with android... text
my computer features : cpu 2ghz celeron ram 512+256
show this message in eclipse

> [2011-01-17 01:05:47 - HelloAndroidWorld] adb is running normally.
>   [2011-01-17 01:05:47 - HelloAndroidWorld] Performing com.taher.android.HelloTaherAndroidWorld activity launch
>   [2011-01-17 01:05:48 - HelloAndroidWorld] Automatic Target Mode: launching new emulator with compatible AVD 'myavd'
>   [2011-01-17 01:05:48 - HelloAndroidWorld] Launching a new emulator with Virtual Device 'myavd'
>   [2011-01-17 01:05:53 - HelloAndroidWorld] New emulator found: emulator-5554
>   [2011-01-17 01:05:53 - HelloAndroidWorld] Waiting for HOME ('android.process.acore') to be launched...
>   [2011-01-17 01:07:12 - HelloAndroidWorld] emulator-5554 disconnected! Cancelling 'com.taher.android.HelloTaherAndroidWorld activity launch'!

please help me tHx

Comment: can every one tell me what is wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I have had a problem similar to this before. For me what worked was waiting until the home screen loaded and then going to the apps screen. My HelloWorld app had an icon on that screen and I was able to click on it to start it and it started running at that point.